# Convert Int8? to UnsafePointer<Int8>?

Tags: c, swift, xcode

I am very new to Swift. Trying to write a Swift app that calls an outside C method. However, the Xcode compiler is giving error about type conversion. The C method prototype is of the form:

```
void * cMethod(const char* string1Path, const char* string2Path, const char* string3Path, const char* string4Path);
```

The gist of the Swift code is:

```
import OpenGLES
import CoreGraphics
import GLKit

var mGLUTWindow: Void?

class myClass {

    mGLUTWindow = nil
    let appBundle = Bundle.main

    let string1 = appBundle.path(forResource: "Init", ofType: "dat")
    let string1Path = Int8((string1?.description)!)

    let string2 = appBundle.path(forResource: "autostart", ofType: "type")
    let string2Path = Int8((string2?.description)!)

    let string3: String? = appBundle.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "") ?? "" + ("/")
    let string3Path = Int8((string3?.description)!)

    mGLUTWindow = cMethod(UnsafePointer(string3Path), string1Path, string2Path, "ios")
}
```

The compiler gives the error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Int8?' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<Int8>?'
```

The C method is being brought in by a bridging header. Is there a way to convert this to the expected argument?

NOTE: The Swift code here was brought over from an Objective-C file from several years ago and is being adapted to Swift. I used [this](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/code/) Obj-C to Swift converter, as I barely understand Swift and cannot read Obj-C. The Obj-C lined I put in were of the form:

```
NSString * string1 = [[appBundle pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@""] stringByAppendingString:@"/"]; 
const char * string1Path = [string1 cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
```

Comment: Why are you trying to convert a path to an integer? That's never going to work.

Comment: Sorry it's just a char. Not a path.

Comment: You're initing it from a path here: `Int8((string1?.description)!)`. That's going to give you `nil` every time.

Comment: So for this Swift code, I am using an Objective-C file from several years ago and trying to adapt it to Swift. I used this obc-c 2 Swift converter (https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/code/), as I barely understand Swift and can't read obj-c. The obj-c line I put in was: `NSString   * string1     = [[appBundle pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@""]
                                 stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
    const char * string1Path = [string1 cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];`

Comment: You should better include such important info into your question. You can edit and update your own question. Better do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were given the C-function and some code shown as your Objective-C lines, I would write something like this:

```
var mGLUTWindow: UnsafeRawPointer?

class MyClass {

    func aMethod() {
        let appBundle = Bundle.main

        let string1 = appBundle.path(forResource: "Init", ofType: "dat")!

        let string2 = appBundle.path(forResource: "autostart", ofType: "type")!

        let string3 = (appBundle.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "") ?? "") + ("/")

        mGLUTWindow = UnsafeRawPointer(cMethod(string3, string1, string2, "ios"))
    }
}
```

In Swift, when you pass `String` to an argument of type `char *`, Swift generates a temporary C-string buffer and pass the address of the buffer, you have no need to call something like `const char * string1Path = [string1 cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];`.

If the `cMethod` keeps any of the pointers for later use, you may need a little more complicated code, but it is not clear that if we need such complicated code as for the current description.

Answer (score 1):

Although converting an `Int8?` to a pointer is simple enough (just unwrap it and use the `&` operator when passing it as an argument), your real problem is that converting your string to an `Int8` in the first place is a mistake. The value that `Bundle.path(forResource:ofType:)` returns is going to be a path, looking something like this:

```
"/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/Init.dat"
```

Meanwhile, you're trying to convert this to an `Int8`, which is an integer type that can store values from -128 to 127, using an initializer that takes a `String`. The reason this initializer returns an optional is because not every string will contain a number between -128 and 127, so if the string is something else, you get `nil`.

A string like `"37"` or `"-101"` would convert properly, but a path string like the one above will always just give you `nil`.

What you actually want to do here is to convert your `String` to a C string. There are a few different ways to do that, but the way I'd do it would be to use `URL`'s `fileSystemRepresentation` feature, like so:

```
let url1 = appBundle.url(forResource: "Init", withExtension: "dat")! // instead of path
url1.withUnsafeFileSystemRepresentation { cPath in
    // cPath here is an UnsafePointer<Int8> that you can pass to C APIs inside this block.
}

// Don't let cPath get out here or bad things will happen.
```

Note that you need to make sure not to let `cPath` escape the `withUnsafeFileSystemRepresentation` block here, because it's not defined to be valid outside of that scope.

Also note that due to the `!`, this will crash your app if the `Init.dat` file doesn't actually exist inside your application, so you'd better make sure you include it.